# IOS/Objective C: How to customize screen based on data

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uilabel

Newb from web background trying to do something that is common on web but may not be possible on iPhone.

I am trying to create a screen for contacts that looks roughly like a business card:

```
John Doe
Vice President
Acme Insurance
222 Main Street
International Plaza
Anytown USA 22333
Tel: 555 555 5555
Fax: 555 555 5555
email: john.doe@acmeco.com
```

If some bit of data is unavailable like fax or title, I'd rather not leave a blank space but rather have next line appear immediately below previous one.

Labels created in storyboard seem to just leave a blank space if there is no data to fill them.

Is there any way to make the labels not take up space if empty or am I stuck with layout in storyboard?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'flow' based layout like in HTML/CSS. There are several ways you could solve this. For example:

1. Use a table view.
2. Use constraints and manually set the height of empty labels to 0.
3. Manually layout your labels.
4. Put everything in one label using line breaks.

What is best depends on how you want your actual view to look. The easiest way is probably #4. The most flexible way is probably #1. But again, it's dependent on your other requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Hidden or empty views still take up space (as you've discovered).  Your best bet might be to only add sub-views to your main view if they are going to contain visible information and then have the layout re-calculated at run-time.

Views can be owned by a view controller without necessarily being part of the display.